# How to get FULL length GPS coordinates?

Tags: android, android-gps

I just found out that my GPS is returning shorter length latitude and longitude coordinates.

It's returning latitude: `00.0000000` (9 chars)
Instead of: `00.00000000000000` (16 chars),

Due to the length, when I use my Geocoder it returns different names of places. How can I receive full-length coordinates?

Here is the code:

```
val listenerMain = object : LocationListener {
  override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
      locationManager.removeUpdates(this)
      lastLatitude = location.latitude
      lastLongitude = location.longitude
  }

  override fun onStatusChanged(s: String, i: Int, bundle: Bundle) { }
  override fun onProviderEnabled(s: String) { }
  override fun onProviderDisabled(s: String) { }
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0f, listenerMain)
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0f, listenerMain)
```

---

`lastLatitude` and `lastLongitude` are 9-chars.

Comment: Perhaps add the code you're using?

Comment: @PGCodeRider It's a simple GPS and NETWORK listeners. When `onLocationChanged` is called, I'm getting the latitude and longitue: `location.getLatitude` and `location.getLongitude`.

Comment: @SET1, without code, it is very unlikely that the question fits here. Please provide the relevant code

Comment: @Derek Code added.

Comment: Those extra decimal points are totally useless - even at the Equator where a degree of latitude is 111 miles, 0.0000001 degrees is only 0.7 inches, which I'd bet is smaller than the precision of your GPS hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common for GPS to return 6-7 digits after the dot. The average GPS EPE (estimated positional error) is in the range of meters for the most parts of the world, and the 6th digit of GPS coordinate is equal to 1e-6 * 111km is about 10cm, which is way above the precision of the GPS itself.

Using 7th digit, which is in single centimeter range, seems to be an overkill, and you're striving for 14th digit?? One millionth part of the centimeter??